# system.design reference issue of WixSharp on .net 4

Tags: .net-4.0, wixsharp

I'm trying to use WixSharp with .net 4, but I got this warning:

*Warning        The currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" does not include "System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which the referenced assembly "WixSharp, Version=1.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3775edd25acc43c2, processorArchitecture=MSIL" depends on. This caused the referenced assembly to not resolve. To fix this, either (1) change the targeted framework for this project, or (2) remove the referenced assembly from the project.*

I checked that System.Design is not referenced. When I tried to add reference to it, it's actually grayed out in add reference dialog.

As a result, just as the warning says,  WixSharp is not resolved, and all namespaces in WixSharp has a missing of reference error.

How should I fix this? compile WixSharp from source?

Fei

Comment: MSBuild is very good at *also* checking the indirect dependencies.  Targeting the client profile is a massive waste of both your time and your users' time, thank heavens it was discontinued.

Comment: it's strange that when I switch the target framework from `.net 4.0 client` to `.net 4`, it compiles OK. So `system.design` only exist in `.net 4 full`?